# How to test response data from Express in Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs, middleware

I'm writing unit tests for separate middleware functions in Node/Express using Jest.

A simple example of the middleware:

```
function sendSomeStuff(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const data = {'some-prop':'some-value'};

        res.json(data);
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
```

And a sample of my test suite:

```
const httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
const { sendSomeStuff } = require('/some/path/to/middleware');

describe('sendSomeStuff', () => {
    test('should send some stuff', () => {
        const request = httpMocks.createRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/some/url'
        });

        let response = httpMocks.createResponse();

        sendSomeStuff(request, response, (err) => {
            expect(err).toBeFalsy();

            // How to 'capture' what is sent as JSON in the function?
        });
    });
});
```

I have to provide a callback to populate the `next` parameter, which is called in the function. Normally, this would 'find the next matching pattern', and pass the `req` and `res` objects to that middleware. However, how can I do this in a test set-up? I need to verify the JSON from the response.

I don't want to touch the middleware itself, it should be contained in the test environment.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found a fix!
Leaving this here for someone else who might struggle with the same.

When returning data using `res.send()`, `res.json()` or something similar, the response object (from `const response = httpMocks.createResponse();`)
itself is updated. The data can be collected using `res._getData()`:

```
const httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
const { sendSomeStuff } = require('/some/path/to/middleware');

describe('sendSomeStuff', () => {
    test('should send some stuff', () => {
        const request = httpMocks.createRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/some/url'
        });

        const response = httpMocks.createResponse();

        sendSomeStuff(request, response, (err) => {
            expect(err).toBeFalsy();
        });

        const { property } = JSON.parse(response._getData());

        expect(property).toBe('someValue');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Mark your answer as correct as well if it solved your problem!

Comment: This needs to be put on a billboard with neon lights around it, I searched high and low until I found this.

Comment: I was worried about using `_getData` because the leading underscore is something I've always understood as "private method, use at your own risk" (meaning it's not part of the API and could change without warning). But it doesn't seem like there's another straight-forward way.

Answer (score 3):

I did a different way by utilising `jest.fn()`. For example:
if you wanna test `res.json({ status: YOUR_RETURNED_STATUS }).status(200);`

```
const res = {};
res.json = jest.fn(resObj => ({
    status: jest.fn(status => ({ res: { ...resObj, statusCode: status } 
  })),
}));
```

Basically, I mock the res chain methods(`json` and `status`).

That way you can do `expect(YOUR_TEST_FUNCTION_CALL).toEqual({ res: { status: 'successful', statusCode: 200 }});` if your response structure is like that.